# possessive, object and reflexive pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns

what's the difference between " a picture of us" , " a picture of ours" and " a picture of ourselves" ?

and, does " a picture of us" really mean that the photo is taken by someone other than the ones in the picture?

or, does " a picture of ours" mean that the ones in the photo took that picture??

Comment: There is no connection of who had taken the photo, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, I'll illustrate the differences between the three phrases you have quoted by means of a concrete example. Namely: *the speaker [in all 3 phrases] is named Alice, and she's referring to herself and her brother Bob as **us**.*

> A picture of us

This phrase just means *a picture which shows the individuals who are the antecedent of the pronoun **us**.* Using our example, the picture shows Alice and Bob. As @Sam commented, *there is no implied suggestion of who did or didn't take the picture*. The picture could have been taken by Alice, Bob, or any other person.

> A picture of ours

This (using "of ours" instead of "of us") conveys a significant difference in meaning - *a picture of ours* means *a picture **belonging** to us*. It does **not** have to *depict* "us"! So, the picture referred to by this phrase must *belong* to Alice and Bob, but *doesn't necessarily show either of them*: it might, for example, be a picture of their friend's cat. This phrase also doesn't give any information as to who took the picture.

> A picture of ourselves

Unlike the other two, this one actually **does** carry the connotation that the picture *both represents and was taken by* the same individuals. This phrase is likely to occur in a context like "We took *a picture of ourselves* by the waterfall." So, the picture shows Alice and Bob, and was taken by either Alice or Bob. I only said *either* (and not *both*) of them because it isn't possible for two people to simultaneously take the same picture, as far as I know.